# php mysql echo ordering

Tags: php, mysql

This is my first time creating php/mysql code from scratch and Im a little lost. I have a tv show I created a mysql database for. My problem is creating the php code that groupies, orders, then echos the database into seasons and episodes.

The question is, how to group my episodes into seasons and then echo them and make sure they are in the correct descending order?

Example

> Season 1
>   Eps 1
>   Eps 2
>   Eps TBA   sub_season_num 3
>   Season 2
>   Eps 1
>   Eps 2
>   ect...

My code is as follows right now.

```
function showerror()
{
die("Whoops " . mysql_errno() . ":" . mysql_error());
}
if (!($result = mysql_query("SELECT season_num, sub_season_num, esp_num, title, descrip    FROM season ORDER BY season_num, sub_season_num", $link))) showerror();
echo "Season 1";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "Episode {$row["esp_num"]}<br>";
echo "Title {$row["title"]}<br>";
echo "Description {$row["descrip"]}<br>";
}
```

My sql database has the following table "season" inside are the following "ID" "season_num" "sub_season_num" "esp_num" "title" "descrip"

Some "esp_num" have a value of (TBA) so I use "sub_season_num" to help order them until an episode number is assigned.

Any help and/or code samples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tested the code? What does it currently output, if anything?

Comment: if you look below in my response to miki you can see that his code gets me 75% of the way there. I just now need to brake up the seasons. So that after everything in season 1 has listed the code then lists everything under season 2.

Comment: could I change `if($currentSeason !== $row->season_num` to `if($currentSeason !== 1` to obtain my desired effect?

Comment: This is where my code stands now
`if (!($result = mysql_query("SELECT season_num, sub_season_num, esp_num, title, descrip FROM season ORDER BY season_num, sub_season_num", $link))) showerror();
$season_one = 1;
$season_two = 2;
echo "Season 1<br>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
if(season_num !== $season_one){
echo "Episode {$row["esp_num"]}<br>";
echo "Title {$row["title"]}<br>";
echo "Description {$row["descrip"]}<br>";
}}
echo "Season 2<br>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
if(season_num !== $season_two){
echo "Episode {$row["esp_num"]}<br>";
ect...`

Comment: can anyone help with the last bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `ORDER BY season_num, sub_season_num` to `ORDER BY season_num, esp_num, sub_season_num`

```
$currentSeason = null;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
if($currentSeason !== $row->season_num){
echo "Season $row->season_num";
$currentSeason = $row->season_num;
}

echo "Episode {$row["esp_num"]}<br>";
echo "Title {$row["title"]}<br>";
echo "Description {$row["descrip"]}<br>";

}
```

Comment: This is where my code stands now `if (!($result = mysql_query("SELECT season_num, sub_season_num, esp_num, title, descrip FROM season ORDER BY season_num, sub_season_num", $link))) showerror(); $season_one = 1; $season_two = 2; echo "Season 1<br>"; while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { if(season_num !== $season_one){ echo "Episode {$row["esp_num"]}<br>"; echo "Title {$row["title"]}<br>"; echo "Description {$row["descrip"]}<br>"; }} echo "Season 2<br>"; while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { if(season_num !== $season_two){ echo "Episode {$row["esp_num"]}<br>"; ect...`